# Decentralized synchronized secure data storage

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, distributed

**Introduction**

Hi, I am going to ask a question which seems *utopic* for me, but I need to know if there is a way to achieve what I need. And if not, I need to know **why not**.

**The idea**

Suppose I have a database structure, in **MySql**.

I want to create some solution to allow anyone *(no matter who, no matter where)* to have a synchronized copy *(updated clone)* of this database *(with its content)*

Well, and it is not going to be just one synchronized copy, it could *(and should)* be a multiple replication *(supposing the basic, this means, for example, ten copies all over the world)*

And, the most important thing: It must be **secure**. By secure I mean only real-accepted transactions will be synchronized with all the others *(no matter how many)* database copies/clones.

*Note*: Since it would be **quite difficult** to make the synchronization in real-time,  I will design everything to make this feature dispensable. So it is not required.

**My auto-suggestion**

This is how I am thinking to manage it:

**Time identifiers and Updates checking**: Every action *(insert, update, delete...)* will be stored as the action instruction itself, associated to the time identifier. *[I think better than a DATETIME field, it'll be an INT one, with the number of miliseconds passed from 1st january 2013 on, for example]*. So each copy is going to ask to the *"neighbour copy"* for new actions done since last update, and execute them after checking they are allowed.

*Problem 1*: the *"neighbour copy"* could be outdated too.
*Solution 1*: do not ask just one neighbour, create a **random list** with some of the copies/clones and ask them for news *(I could avoid the **list** and ask ALL the clones for updates, but this will be inefficient if clones number ascends too much)*.

*Problem 2*: Real-time global synchronization is not active. What if...

```
   Someone at CLONE_ENTERPRISING inserts a row into TABLE.
   ... this row goes to every clone ...
   Someone at CLONE_FIXEMALL deletes this row.
   ... and at the same time, somewhere in an outdated clone ...
   Someone at CLONE_DROPOUT edits this row (now inexistent at the other clones)
```

*Solution 2*: easy stuff, force a GLOBAL synchronization before doing any new "*depending-on-third-data* action"  *(edit, for example)*. This global synch. will be unnecessary when making an INSERT, for instance.

*Note*: Well, someone could have some fun, and make the same insert in two clones... since they're not getting updated in real-time, this row will exist twice. But, it's the same as when we have one single database, in some needed cases we check if there is an existing same-row before doing the final action. Not a problem.

*Problem 3*: It is possible to edit the code and do not filter actions, so someone could spread instructions to delete everything, or just make some trolling activity. This is not a problem, since good clones will always be somewhere. Those who got bad won't interest anymore.

I really appreciate if you read. I know this is not the perfect solution, it has possibly hundred of holes, but it is my basic start. I will now appreciate anything you can teach me now. Thanks a lot.

**PS.:** It could be that all this I am trying already exists and has its own name. Sorry for asking then *(I'd anyway thank this name, if it exists)*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a look at [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sync/bb736753.aspx) from Microsoft. It might be better suited to SQL Server but it should work with MySQL too. The problem you are tackling is quite a complex one.