# Public but still secure user authentication

Tags: authentication, passwords

**Introduction**

I came along this scenario while trying to find out a way to build a [Decentralized and synchronized database structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409724/decentralized-synchronized-secure-data-storage) which is open to everyone. Since both source code and database are public, I need to find out if there's a way to achieve a secure user authentication system. And if not, I'd like to know **why not** *(it's not so obvious)*.

**My idea is the next:**

Suppose that I make it compulsory for users to have a password with numbers, capital letters and symbols *(making it random so it does not appear in any dictionary)*. If I then use a hashing method with the greatest uniqueness, the possibility to crack this password will be very little.

**Main problems:**

- Cracking dictionaries may content also those random-strange passwords.
- Even if possibilites of cracking are few, crackers have all the time they want.

**There must be an alternative:**

Maybe I have to change the traditional *user/password* method, and make up something different. One solution could be sending each time a temporary access link to the user's mail *(for which no one but himself knows password)*, but this is not a nice/comfortable way to access a website.

Thanks for reading. If you thing that I am trying something stupid, let me know and I'll be pleased *(but I'd also appreciate a demonstration of my stupidity)*. Really, thanks.

**Edit**: I know I could use a third party service, like [OpenId](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)... but this is also a curiosity question for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

> "making it random so it does not appear in any dictionary"

You can't assume that. There are dictionaries with passwords made up of symbols and different characters.

Did you try having a look at [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29)?
I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but I think You need to implement something like Kerberos.

Comment: Hi, thank you answering. I already considered what you're telling me *(and described it at the MAIN PROBLEMS list)*. Gonna take a look at Kereberos, but I think it requires a secure third party, which I do not have.

Comment: You could set up your own ticket granting server. It wont exactly be kerberos but but will be a ticket granting scheme.